# NOOBS is stuck on, “The install process will begin shortly.”

Tags: windows-iot, noobs, operating-systems

I’m installing windows IoT and “The install process will begin shortly.” has been on the screen for a while. Is the os downloading? Did something fail to install/download? Safe to cut power?

Comment: Are you still waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has failed to download or your SDCard is fake or end-of-life.

You need to ask yourself "what does NOOBS give me?"

If the answer is "A way to install Raspbian." then you should ditch NOOBS and go with Etcher (from https://etcher.io) and plain Raspbian 2018-11-13 (from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest).

If the answer is "Multiple operating systems and a boot manager." then you should ditch NOOBS and go with PINN (from https://github.com/procount/pinn) which is a much improved version of NOOBS which won't exhibit the problem you're seeing.

If you choose PINN you need a 32GB SDCard to make it useful.